# how to create Function Selector (Method IDs)

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, nodejs, abi

As stated in ABI specs that `0xcdcd77c0: the Method ID. This is derived as the first 4 bytes of the Keccak hash of the ASCII form of the signature baz(uint32,bool).`

So, I have to create **method IDs** (function selectors) of my contract functions through javascript/nodejs/web3js. Suppose i have an array of functions name  and their parameters (extracted from ABI JSON file)-  i.e. `funcNameAndParams[]`. One of its element is as follow;

```
{
  contractNo: 0,
  funcName: 'getSupplyRate',
  params: [ 'address', 'uint256', 'uint256' ]
}
```

1. Is it possible to generate Method IDs, having above
   information ? if yes, how could i proceed ? I have read [ABI specs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html)
    but could not found how to code it in JavaScript/Nodejs/web3.js
2. If I have contract source code as well, then could i proceed ? Means generating Methods IDs from json ABIs will be easy or from .sol file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With web3.js v1.2.x, you can use function [`web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctionsignature):

```
const selector = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature({
    type: "function",
    name: yourObj.funcName,
    inputs: yourObj.params.map(param => ({type: param}))
});
```

Or simply:

```
const selector = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature("getSupplyRate(address,uint256,uint256)");
```

In the second example, note that you should avoid any spaces between the parameter types.

Comment: thanks a lot... works for me...

Comment: @AmirAli: NP :)